# Why need to set schema when transforming JavaRDD<Row> to DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark

Why does method `createDataFrame(JavaRDD<Row> javaRDD, StructType schema)` need to set a schema while `Row` has schema in itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Row` may have schema field but it is not required. `o.a.s.sql.Row` simply sets schema to `null`.
- Schema doesn't affect the type so there is no way to enforce uniform data model. Explicit `DataFrame` schema serves as a single source of truth.
- It wouldn't be possible to determine schema without reading data what would be yet another way to break laziness.